# req.GetApiKey() doesn't execute any query in DB ServiceStack ApiKeyAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

Here is my auth config

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),

                    new IAuthProvider[]
                    {
                        new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) {RequireSecureConnection = false }
                    })
                {
                    IncludeRegistrationService = true,

                });
```

Global filter

```
 GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
                {
                    LastApiKey = req.GetApiKey();

                });
```

I have generated Api key in DB and trying to pass the key through postman or JsonServiceClient with Basic Authentication having API key in Username of Http request. I tried to pass bearer token in Http request too but not able to get api key from req.GetApiKey(). When I see through SQL profiler it doesn't show any query executed. However I am able to resolve IManageApiKeys and able to execute it's methods. Do I need any attribute in my service or any additional configuration in AppHost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack's [API Key Auth Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider) works by setting up an Authenticated User Session on the Request for [successful API Key Authentication requests](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider#interoperable). When setting up the Authenticated User Session the [API Key that was used to authenticate](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider#simple-and-integrated) is stored in `IRequest.Items` Dictionary which is what [IRequest.GetApiKey() Extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/2233d0d465e9e6238a99a8fed8888c213802c9b9/src/ServiceStack/Auth/ApiKeyAuthProvider.cs#L470) is returning.

So `IRequest.GetApiKey()` isn't making any DB calls, that was already done initially when setting up the Authenticated User Session.

Authentication is performed when it's required, e.g. when your Services are annotated with any of the Authentication Attributes below:

- `[Authenticate]`
- `[RequiredRole]` / `[RequiresAnyRole]`
- `[RequiredPermission]` / `[RequiresAnyPermission]`

Comment: What I was missing [Authenticate] attribute was applying on api service method and did not work. When I applied on service class it worked as expected. Thank you @mythz.

Comment: @Anuj FYI this is because when the `[Authenticate]` attribute is on the action, it's executed after the GlobalRequestFilters are run, but `base.Request.GetApiKey()` will still be there when the Service is executed.